# Kotlin Flow<T> with Resilience4j RateLimiter and Retry

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I have Resilience4j version: 1.7.1, Kotlin version: 1.7.0, Kotlin Coroutines: 1.6.1.

I'd like to use RateLimiter and Retry in kotlin code, but documentations don't contain information how to use Kotlin Flow with them.

I have a simple code:

```
suspend main() {
    val rateLimiterConfig = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
            .limitForPeriod(2)
            .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .build()
        val rateLimiter = RateLimiter.of("rate-limiter", rateLimiterConfig)
    
        val retryConfig = RetryConfig.custom<Any>()
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .retryExceptions(Exception::class.java)
            .build()
        val retry = Retry.of("retry", retryConfig)
    
        coroutineScope {
           flowOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
                .rateLimiter(rateLimiter)
                .retry(retry)
                .map { async { process(it) } }
                .toList().awaitAll()
        }
}

suspend fun process(num: Int): Int {
    println("time: ${getTime()}, value: $num")
    if(num >= 8) throw Exception()
    delay(1000)
    return num * num
}
```

And I don't have any limiting or retry.
If run this code with printing time(mm:ss.SSS) and incoming value, I have this:

```
time: 46:26.488,value: 7
time: 46:26.488,value: 4
time: 46:26.488,value: 3
time: 46:26.488,value: 1
time: 46:26.488,value: 6
time: 46:26.488,value: 5
time: 46:26.488,value: 8
time: 46:26.488,value: 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at MainKt.process(Main.kt:165)
    at MainKt$main$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:142)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

How does it work?

Comment: Could you update the code snippet, so that one can see where does this time printing take place?

Comment: Michal Fudala,  code was updated

Comment: Hey! I'm having a very similar issue, but just with Retry, not Flow. Does this Retry work for you when there is an exception? I have a very similar setup but the Retry config never catches the exception and it is thrown like normal.

How do you get your retry to work on exceptions? I have the same library and kotlin versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
coroutineScope {
    flowOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
        .rateLimiter(rateLimiter)
        .map { process(it) }
        .retry(retry)
        .toList()
}
```

#### 1. Retries

`retry` from Resilience4j uses `Flow.retryWhen` under the hood. To make it work you have to use it **after** `.map` invocation. Also, `.retry` operator will retry the whole *flow*, not only the failed operation.

[`kotlinx.coroutines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/retry-when.html) docs:

> Retries collection of the given flow when an exception occurs in the upstream flow and the predicate returns true.

> This operator is transparent to exceptions that occur in downstream flow and does not retry on exceptions that are thrown to cancel the flow.

#### 2. Rate limiting

Using `async { }` and then `.awaitAll` kinda parallelizes the whole process, so `rateLimiter` won't be able to do its job. Just do `.map { process(it) }`.